# Placing image on bottom right corner of table cell does not work in Firefox and Safari

Tags: asp.net

I have the following table structure in my aspx page. I need to place the image at bottom right corner of a table cell. The code below works fine for IE and Chrome. But in Firefox and Safari, the image is displayed at the bottom right corner of the row, and not the cell.

```
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
     <td valign="top" style="width:20%; position:relative">
      <div>
         //some controls here
      </div> 
      <img src="~/images/Index.JPG" runat="server" style="position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0"/> 
     </td>
     <td valign="top" style="width:80%">
      <div>
        //control here

      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
    &nbsp;
    <tr>
     <td align="center" colspan="1" style="width: 20%">
       //control here
      </td>
      <td align="center" colspan="2" style="width: 80%">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="width:100%" colspan="2">
       //control here
       </td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Please help with this!!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding another row for the image and setting its alignment.

```
         <tr>
           <td style="width: 20%;" align="right" valign="bottom">
             <asp:Image ID="Img1" runat="server" />

           </td>
         </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the position:relative of the parent td for this image as the absolute of the images is done relative to the td that has the position:relative

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
     <td valign="top" style="width:20%;">
      <div>
         //some controls here
      </div> 
      <img src="~/images/Index.JPG" runat="server" style="position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0"/> 
     </td>
     <td valign="top" style="width:80%">
      <div>
        //control here

      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
    &nbsp;
    <tr>
     <td align="center" colspan="1" style="width: 20%">
       //control here
      </td>
      <td align="center" colspan="2" style="width: 80%">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="width:100%" colspan="2">
       //control here
       </td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: If I remove position:relative, it stops working in IE and Chrome also. The image is displayed at bottom right corner of the row rather than the cell.

Comment: I think this image is an absolute image that will appear in the bottom of the page whatever it's location in the html so i think you can put it fist thing in the html after the <body> tag to make sure that it will appear in the bottom in all browsers and to ensure that no other positioning will affect it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Samir. But the image is added inside a td tag of table. The width and height of this tag is not fixed and can increase or decrease. So, I cannot fix the position of this image. It has to move along with the table cell.